# Xcode: I Can't Set an NSUserdefault to itself + 5

Tags: ios, xcode

This is for iOS

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"money"] = 
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"money"] + 5;
```

Could Someone Please Help Me With This, I'm Getting This Error:

> Assigning to 'readonly' return result of an Objective-C message not allowed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`integerForKey` is a `getter` method. used  `setInteger` setter method for setting property like as bellowed.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"money"] + 5 forKey:@"money"];
```

Hope this help you.